# Passing NSSet and initialize it with values

Tags: nsarray, foundation, nsset, nsmutableset

in main function I have a set

```
    NSMutableSet *set1 = [[NSMutableSet alloc ]init];
    NSMutableSet *set2 = [[NSMutableSet alloc ]init];
```

and I want to have a functions that can "initialize" with some values.

Like(but not work) :

```
void initSet (NSMutableSet *set1, NSMutableSet *set2)
{
    NSArray *a1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: intNum(1), intNum(2), nil];
    NSArray *a2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:intNum(3), intNum(4), intNum(5), intNum(6), intNum(7), nil];

    set1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray: a1];
    set2 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray: a2];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sets need to be passed as pointers to pointers. Secause regular pointers are passed by value, modifications to `set1` and `set2` do not change the values that you pass to `initSet` from the caller.

```
void initSet (NSMutableSet **set1, NSMutableSet **set2)
{
    NSArray *a1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: intNum(1), intNum(2), nil];
    NSArray *a2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:intNum(3), intNum(4), intNum(5), intNum(6), intNum(7), nil];

    *set1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray: a1];
    *set2 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray: a2];
}
```

Call this function as follows:

```
NSMutableSet *s1, *s2;
initSet(&s1, &s2);
```